# Separate ASP.NET Applications, Shared Sessions?

Tags: asp.net, session, authentication

I am working on a few applications. I like to keep my applications small, but I'd like to make it so that users that utilize more than one of these programs don't need to login to each application - it would remember and share session info. across the applications. Any thoughts on how I could accomplish this? Here are some examples of the separate applications I have / am working on:

- Housing Room Signup
- Forms
- Student Life

I'd also have a dashboard application that would provide centralized insight into one's responsibilities and point one to applications that needed to be "processed" (e.g. "You haven't signed up for a room" or "You haven't filed x paperwork")

Comment: Please be specific about what you mean by "session". Do you just mean shared authentication, shared profile, or do you mean to share application state between applications?

Comment: Well, I'm using AD authentication - so it is shared in that sense. I'd like the applications to recognize that if someone has a valid session with x1 application that x2, x3, x4 can also accept that the user has in a sense already logged into them as well. I don't particularly need to share the profile or application state - though perhaps profile would become useful eventually.

Comment: Since you are using Active Directory authentication, why are you having them log in at all?

Comment: We don't all use IE for web browsing - in fact we tend to use Firefox or Chrome, so you still have to enter your credentials.

Answer (score 1):

If these are all under the same domain (e.g., http://server/app1 and http://server/app2, http://server/app3 etc.) then you can use a cookie that's set to be valid at the root level.

If not, then you need to adopt a single sign-on concept where the user is redirected to a central authority or login page that applies to all resources every time there's a need to authenticate.